# ggplot2 stagger axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am making a ggplot. The x-axis are factors, and the labels are long.

I can't shorten the labels, they're as short as they can be.

I am interested to make it so that labels are vertically offset. My preference would be to have every odd label at height 0, and every even at height 2 units more distant from the x-axis.

I have looked here, [ggplot-hopeful-help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492777/staggered-axis-labels-in-ggplot2), but have real trouble interpreting what is going on, and so can't make a useful version of this.

Any ideas??

(example code below... I'm not very good at formatting code here, it appears... sry.)

```
library("ggplot2"); 
stack <- data.frame(value =rnorm(n = 1000, sd = 2, mean=34)); stack$fact <- as.factor(rep(1:5, each=1000/5));
ggplot(stack, aes(x=fact, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=fact))+ scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), labels=c("hi","don't suggest I shorten the text","I need long labels", "This is a long factor label","This label is very long"))
```

Comment: The answer you are referening to, gives you solution you are looking for. For your case it would be `+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = grid::unit(c(-2, 0), "points")))` where -2 will be for the odd labels and 0 for the even labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `guide_axis` was added in version `3.3.0` `ggplot2` now offers an out-of-the-box option to place axis labels on multiple rows using the `n.dogde` argument of `guide_axis`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

stack <- data.frame(value = rnorm(n = 1000, sd = 2, mean = 34))
stack$fact <- as.factor(rep(1:5, each = 1000 / 5))

ggplot(stack, aes(x = fact, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = fact)) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    breaks = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
    labels = c(
      "hi", "don't suggest I shorten the text", "I need long labels",
      "This is a long factor label", "This label is very long"
    ),
    guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Understand it or not, it seems to work pretty well. Calling the plot in your question `your_plot`:

```
your_plot + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = grid::unit(c(-2, 0, 2), "points")))
```

[image]

Specifying preferences in `theme()` is the way to make adjustments to the trappings of your ggplot. `axis.text.x` is modifying only the x-axis text, which is created with preferences set by `element_text()`. You could specify the font size, the font family, an angle for rotation, etc., in `element_text()`. `vjust` stands for "vertical justification", so setting the `vjust` to three values, -2, 0 and 2 is applying those values to successive x-axis labels. (Apparently the negative is up, which surprised me.)

Using `grid::unit()` allows us to specify the units (in this case points) by which the text is vertically moved. Looking at `?grid::units` reveals that you could use inches, cm, or several other units.

The only problem is the overlap with the x axis title. I think the easiest way to fix this is to add a couple linebreaks `"\n"` before it:

```
your_plot + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = grid::unit(c(-2, 0, 2), "points"))) +
    labs(x = "\n\nfact")
```

[image]

Another solution would be to rotate the text:

```
your_plot + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0, vjust = 0))
```

[image]

For more reading, [there's a whole vignette on ggplot2 theming](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html).

Comment: perfect. I had the whole object wrapped in pdf(), so the final configuration that worked for me was:
'pdf("my.file.pdf")
my.plot +   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = grid::unit(c(-2, -0.1, 1.2), "points")))
dev.off()

Comment: I'd generally recommend using `ggsave()` rather than `pdf()... dev.off()` when working with ggplots.

Answer (score 0):

```
stack <- data.frame(value =rnorm(n = 1000, sd = 2, mean=34))
stack$fact <- as.factor(rep(1:5, each=1000/5))

ggplot(stack, aes(x=fact, y=value)) + 
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=fact)) + 
scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), labels=c("hi","don't suggest I shorten the text","I need long labels", "This is a long factor label","This label is very long"))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = grid::unit(c(0, 2), "points"))) + 
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.6))
```

Actually the solution discussed in  [the link you reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492777/staggered-axis-labels-in-ggplot2) required only slight modification.
I also added

```
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.6))
```

to lower x-axis label to prevent overlapping.