# Multiple Line Chart using R (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, linechart

I am attempting to make a multiple line chart in R using ggplot and am trying to figure out how to not have the x-axis labels overlap (something that looks like th first image below):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFRQP.png)

This is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyrS4.png)

This is the output of my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYhfo.png)

Is there a function or parameter to adjust the placement of the x-axis labels to be adjusted like the first image?

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878974/wrap-long-axis-labels-via-labeller-label-wrap-in-ggplot2

Comment: You could also try with `scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))` to place the labels in multiple rows as in the image you posted.

Comment: Check out these links stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example as this will help people to answer you question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One idea you could try is to rotate the x axis labels instead of staggering them:

```
your_plot + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0, vjust = 0))
```

This related question has other ideas: [ggplot2 stagger axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529116/ggplot2-stagger-axis-labels)