# Alternating Vertical X-axis label in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to find a way to visualise the x-axis labels more clearly if you have crowded data. Making the labels vertical does good job. Is it possible to arrange the labels alternating to let's say the axis, so that spaces between the labels become clearer.

Example:

`name = replicate(100, expr = paste(sample(LETTERS, 5), collapse = ""))
value = sample(1:2000, 100, replace = TRUE)
df = data.frame(name, value)`

barplot using `library(ggplot2)`

`ggplot(df, aes(name, value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))`

It is still crowded. How can I arrange the labels alternating both up and down of the x-axis or a line below it.

[image]

Comment: do you mean, e.g. odd labels along the bottom margin and even labels along the top margin?

Comment: yes, that would be nice

Comment: perhaps you can adapt one of these strategies : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717545/add-secondary-x-axis-labels-to-ggplot-with-one-x-axis

Comment: Can you modify one of [these?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942816/change-label-of-yaxis-face-in-plot-with-ggplot-package-r/40966343#40966343)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to modify your plot to suit my requirement. Great solution. Learned a lot.