# Axis labels on two lines with nested x variables (year below months)

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, axis-labels

I would like to display months (in abbreviated form) along the horizontal axis, with the corresponding year printed once. I know how to display month-year:

[image]

The un-needed repetition of the year clutters the labels. Instead I would like something like this:

[image]

except that the year would be printed **below**  the months.

I printed the year above the axis labels, because that's the best I could do. This follows a limitation of the `annotate()` function, which gets clipped if it lies outside of the plot area. I am aware of possible workarounds based on `annotate_custom()`, but I couldn't make them to work with date objects (I did not try to convert dates to numbers and back to dates again, as it seemed more complicated than hopefully necessary)

I'm wondering if the new `dup_axis()` could be hijacked for this purpose. If instead of sending the duplicated axis to the opposite side of the panel, it could send it a few lines below the duplicated axis, then perhaps it would just be a matter of setting up one axis with `panel.grid.major` blanked out and the labels set to `%b`,  while the other axis would have `panel.grid.minor` blanked out and the labels set to `%Y`. (an added challenge is that the year labels would be shifted to October instead of January)

These questions are related. However, the `annotate_custom()` function and `textGrob()` functions do not play well with dates, as far as I can tell.

[how-can-i-add-annotations-below-the-x-axis-in-ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079210/how-can-i-add-annotations-below-the-x-axis-in-ggplot2)

[displaying-text-below-the-plot-generated-by-ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014187/displaying-text-below-the-plot-generated-by-ggplot2)

Data and basic code below:

```
    library("ggplot2")
    library("scales")
    ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date, y = value)) + geom_line() +
        scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 month", date_minor_breaks = "1 month", labels = date_format("%b %Y")) +
        xlab(NULL)

    ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date, y = value)) + geom_line() +
        scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks = "2 month", labels = date_format("%b")) +   
        annotate(geom = "text", x = as.Date("1719-10-01"), y = 0, label = "1719") +
        annotate(geom = "text", x = as.Date("1720-10-01"), y = 0, label = "1720") +
        xlab(NULL)


    # data
    df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(-91455, -91454, -91453, -91452, 
    -91451, -91450, -91448, -91447, -91446, -91445, -91444, -91443, 
    -91441, -91440, -91439, -91438, -91437, -91436, -91434, -91433, 
    -91431, -91430, -91429, -91427, -91426, -91425, -91424, -91423, 
    -91422, -91420, -91419, -91418, -91417, -91416, -91415, -91413, 
    -91412, -91411, -91410, -91409, -91408, -91406, -91405, -91404, 
    -91403, -91402, -91401, -91399, -91398, -91397, -91396, -91395, 
    -91394, -91392, -91391, -91390, -91389, -91388, -91387, -91385, 
    -91384, -91382, -91381, -91380, -91379, -91377, -91376, -91375, 
    -91374, -91373, -91372, -91371, -91370, -91369, -91368, -91367, 
    -91366, -91364, -91363, -91362, -91361, -91360, -91359, -91357, 
    -91356, -91355, -91354, -91353, -91352, -91350, -91349, -91348, 
    -91347, -91346, -91345, -91343, -91342, -91341, -91340, -91339, 
    -91338, -91336, -91335, -91334, -91333, -91332, -91331, -91329, 
    -91328, -91327, -91326, -91325, -91324, -91322, -91321, -91320, 
    -91319, -91315, -91314, -91313, -91312, -91311, -91310, -91308, 
    -91307, -91306, -91305, -91304, -91303, -91301, -91300, -91299, 
    -91298, -91297, -91296, -91294, -91293, -91292, -91291, -91290, 
    -91289, -91287, -91286, -91285, -91284, -91283, -91282, -91280, 
    -91279, -91278, -91277, -91276, -91275, -91273, -91272, -91271, 
    -91270, -91269, -91268, -91266, -91265, -91264, -91263, -91262, 
    -91261, -91259, -91258, -91257, -91256, -91255, -91254, -91252, 
    -91251, -91250, -91249, -91248, -91247, -91245, -91244, -91243, 
    -91242, -91241, -91240, -91238, -91237, -91236, -91235, -91234, 
    -91233, -91231, -91230, -91229, -91228, -91227, -91226, -91224, 
    -91223, -91222, -91221, -91220, -91219, -91217, -91216, -91215, 
    -91214, -91213, -91212, -91210, -91209, -91208, -91207, -91205, 
    -91201, -91200, -91199, -91198, -91196, -91195, -91194, -91193, 
    -91192, -91191, -91189, -91188, -91187, -91186, -91185, -91184, 
    -91182, -91181, -91180, -91179, -91178, -91177, -91175, -91174, 
    -91173, -91172, -91171, -91170, -91168, -91167, -91166, -91165, 
    -91164, -91163, -91161, -91160, -91159, -91158, -91157, -91156, 
    -91154, -91153, -91152, -91151, -91150, -91149, -91147, -91146, 
    -91145, -91144, -91143, -91142, -91140, -91139, -91138, -91131, 
    -91130, -91129, -91128, -91126, -91125, -91124, -91123, -91122, 
    -91121, -91119, -91118, -91117, -91116, -91115, -91114, -91112, 
    -91111, -91110, -91109, -91108, -91107, -91104, -91103, -91102, 
    -91101, -91100, -91099, -91097, -91096, -91095, -91094, -91093, 
    -91091, -91090, -91089, -91088, -91087, -91086, -91084, -91083, 
    -91082, -91081, -91080, -91079, -91077, -91076, -91075, -91074, 
    -91073, -91072, -91070, -91069, -91068, -91065, -91063, -91062, 
    -91061, -91060, -91059, -91058, -91056, -91055, -91054, -91053, 
    -91052, -91051, -91049, -91048, -91047, -91046, -91045, -91044, 
    -91042, -91041, -91040, -91039, -91038, -91037, -91035, -91034, 
    -91033, -91032, -91031, -91030, -91028, -91027, -91026, -91025, 
    -91024, -91023, -91021, -91020, -91019, -91018, -91017, -91016, 
    -91014, -91013, -91012, -91011, -91010, -91009, -91007, -91006, 
    -91005, -91004, -91003, -91002, -91000, -90999, -90998, -90997, 
    -90996, -90995, -90993, -90992, -90991, -90990, -90989, -90988, 
    -90986, -90985, -90984, -90983, -90982), class = "Date"), value = c(113, 
    113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 115, 115, 115, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
    117, 117, 117, 117, 116, 117, 116, 116, 116, 117, 117, 117, 117, 
    117, 117, 117, 116, 117, 116, 116, 116, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 
    117, 117, 116, 116, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 
    117, 117, 118, 118, 118, 118, 117, 118, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 
    117, 118, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 117, 117, 118, 118, 
    118, 118, 118, 119, 120, 120, 119, 119, 120, 120, 121, 121, 122, 
    124, 124, 122, 123, 124, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 124, 124, 126, 
    126, 126, 126, 126, 125, 125, 126, 127, 126, 126, 125, 126, 126, 
    126, 128, 128, 128, 130, 133, 131, 133, 134, 134, 134, 136, 136, 
    136, 135, 135, 135, 136, 136, 136, 136, 135, 135, 135, 135, 130, 
    129, 129, 130, 131, 136, 138, 155, 157, 161, 170, 174, 168, 165, 
    169, 171, 181, 184, 182, 179, 181, 179, 175, 177, 177, 174, 170, 
    174, 173, 178, 173, 178, 179, 182, 184, 184, 180, 181, 182, 182, 
    184, 184, 188, 195, 198, 220, 255, 275, 350, 310, 315, 320, 320, 
    316, 300, 310, 310, 320, 317, 313, 312, 310, 297, 285, 285, 286, 
    288, 315, 328, 338, 344, 345, 352, 352, 342, 335, 343, 340, 342, 
    339, 337, 336, 336, 342, 347, 352, 352, 351, 352, 352, 351, 352, 
    352, 355, 375, 400, 452, 487, 476, 475, 473, 485, 500, 530, 595, 
    720, 720, 770, 750, 770, 750, 735, 740, 745, 735, 700, 700, 750, 
    760, 755, 755, 760, 760, 765, 950, 950, 950, 875, 875, 875, 880, 
    880, 880, 900, 900, 900, 880, 880, 890, 895, 890, 880, 870, 870, 
    870, 870, 870, 860, 860, 860, 860, 850, 840, 810, 820, 810, 810, 
    805, 810, 805, 820, 815, 820, 805, 790, 800, 780, 760, 765, 750, 
    740, 820, 810, 800, 800, 775, 750, 810, 750, 740, 700, 705, 660, 
    630, 640, 595, 590, 570, 565, 535, 440, 400, 410, 400, 405, 390, 
    370, 300, 300, 180, 200, 310, 290, 260, 260, 275, 260, 270, 265, 
    255, 250, 210, 210, 200, 195, 210, 215, 240, 240, 220, 220, 220, 
    220, 210, 212, 208, 220, 210, 212, 208, 220, 215, 220, 214, 214, 
    213, 212, 210, 210, 195, 195, 160, 160, 175, 205, 210, 208, 197, 
    181, 185)), .Names = c("Date", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 393L
    ), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: why not just use `colour = format(Date,"%Y")` in the `aes()`. It is cleaner imo instead of trying to hack together a custom x-axis.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571306/multi-row-x-axis-labels-in-ggplot-line-chart

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The code below provides two potential options for adding year labels.

#### Option 1a: Faceting

You could use faceting to mark the years. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

ggplot(df, aes(Date, value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%b", date_breaks="month", expand=c(0,0)) +
  facet_grid(~ year(Date), space="free_x", scales="free_x", switch="x") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_rect(fill=NA,colour="grey50"),
        panel.spacing=unit(0,"cm"))
```

[image]

Note that with this approach, if there are missing dates at the beginning or end of a year (by "missing", I mean rows for those dates are not even present in the data) then the x-axis will start/end at the first/last date in the data for that year, rather than go from Jan-1 to Dec-31. In that case, you'd need to add in rows for the missing dates and either `NA` for `value` or interpolate `value`. In addition, with this method there is no space or line between December 31 of one year and January 1 of the next year, so there's a discontinuity across each year.

#### Option 1b: Faceting + centered month labels

To address @AF7's comment. You can center the month labels by adding some spaces before each label. But you have to choose the number of spaces manually, depending on the physical size of the plot when you print it to a device. (There's probably a way to center the labels programmatically based on the internal grob measurements, but I'm not sure how to do it.) I've also removed the minor vertical gridlines and lightened the line between years.

```
ggplot(df, aes(Date, value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels=paste(c(rep(" ",11), "%b"), collapse=""), 
               date_breaks="month", expand=c(0,0)) +
  facet_grid(~ year(Date), space="free_x", scales="free_x", switch="x") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour="grey70"),
        panel.spacing=unit(0,"cm"))
```

[image]

#### Option 2a: Edit the x-axis label grob

Here's a more complex and finicky method (though it could likely be automated by someone who understands the structure and unit spacings of grid graphics better than I do) that avoids the pitfalls of the faceting method described above:

```
library(grid)

# Fake data with an extra year added for illustration
set.seed(2)
df = data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("1718-03-01"),as.Date("1721-09-20"), by="1 day"))
df$value = cumsum(rnorm(nrow(df)))

# The plot we'll start with
p = ggplot(df, aes(Date, value)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(df$Date[yday(df$Date)==1]), colour="grey60") +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%b", date_breaks="month", expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(x="")
```

[image]

Now we want to add the year values below and in between June and July of each year. The code below does that by modifying the x-axis label grob and is adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38024936/496488) by @SandyMuspratt.

```
# Get the grob
g <- ggplotGrob(p)

# Get the y axis
index <- which(g$layout$name == "axis-b")  # Which grob
xaxis <- g$grobs[[index]]   

# Get the ticks (labels and marks)
ticks <- xaxis$children[[2]]

# Get the labels
ticksB <- ticks$grobs[[2]]

# Edit x-axis label grob
# Find every index of Jun in the x-axis labels and add a newline and
# then a year label
junes = which(ticksB$children[[1]]$label == "Jun")
ticksB$children[[1]]$label[junes] = paste0(ticksB$children[[1]]$label[junes],
                                           "\n      ", unique(year(df$Date))) 

# Put the edited labels back into the plot
ticks$grobs[[2]] <- ticksB
xaxis$children[[2]] <- ticks
g$grobs[[index]] <- xaxis

# Draw the plot
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

#### Option 2b: Edit the x-axis label grob and center the month labels

Below is the only change that needs to be made to Option 2a to center the month labels, but, once again, the number of spaces needs to be tweaked manually.

```
# Make the edit
# Center the month labels between ticks
ticksB$children[[1]]$label = paste0(paste(rep(" ",7),collapse=""), ticksB$children[[1]]$label)

# Find every index of Jun in the x-axis labels and a year label
junes = grep("Jun", ticksB$children[[1]]$label)
ticksB$children[[1]]$label[junes] = paste0(ticksB$children[[1]]$label[junes], "\n      ", unique(year(df$Date)))
```

[image]

Comment: That's even better than what I was trying to do! Thanks!

Comment: With the first method, maybe something like `panel.border = element_rect(colour="grey80")`. WIth the second method, change the `geom_vline` color to change the prominence of the line or just remove the `geom_vline` statement completely if you don't want to demarcate the years.

Comment: I find this x-scale a little bit misleading. I would say that the best way would be to have months surrounded by ticks, so that, e.g. "Jan" starts with a tick and ends with a tick. Currently, January starts with "Jan" and ends with "Feb". This is usually fine for numbers, but is a bit misleading for months imho. Thus I would shift the tick labels to the right by a small amount (half the width of a tick).

Comment: It just gets better every time! Comments: __1__ ``xlab("")`` is important to make space to print the year. Thus, ``xlab(NULL)`` won't give that space. __2__ To prevent labels from clattering, the output needs to be large enough, e.g. ggsave(g, file = "a.pdf", width = 12, height = 4). __3__ you can still set ``date_breaks = "2 month"``, but then the tweaking of label placements needs to be adapted.

Comment: Does the centering of the labels survive printing with ``ggsave``? (I'm using the 4 years of data you gave, printing to pdf or png with ``width = 12`` and am not observing the centering of labels of option 2b)

Comment: My plot goes from 01/01/2010 to 06/30/2015. I don't have enough room on the x-axis to keep the first 3 letters of each month. I kept the labels J,F,M,A,M,J,J,.... You use 'Jun' to set the position of the year labels,  The only work around I could think of was to change "J" for June to " J ", and change `junes = grep("June", ticksB$children[[1]]$label)` to `junes = grep(" J ", ticksB$children[[1]]$label)` (space before and after J for June). This adds extra spacing around the June labels. How could I fix this? Here's [how my plot looks](https://s1.postimg.org/5kikkc9msv/test_plot.png)

Answer (score 15):

I came upon this question and thought maybe I can add a solution. We can display both month and year in every year's first displayed month by using a simple condition. You can play with the `date_breaks` to remove January from the labels, and this will still work. I'm using `month()` and `year()` from `lubridate`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
   ggplot(aes(Date, value)) +
   geom_line() +
   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 months", 
                labels = function(x) if_else(is.na(lag(x)) | !year(lag(x)) == year(x), 
                                             paste(month(x, label = TRUE), "\n", year(x)), 
                                             paste(month(x, label = TRUE))))
```

[image]

Comment: neat trick! The function ``if_else`` is from package ``dplyr`` (part of ``tidyverse``).

Answer (score 9):

If you want to try to hack together a sub-label, you could convert it to a `grob`. I edited this from the original post to create a function that adds the sublabels and returns a `gtable` object. Note that the `sublabs` input must be the same length as your x-axis breaks:

```
library(grid)
library(gtable)
library(gridExtra)

add_sublabs <- function(plot, sublabs){

  gg <- ggplotGrob(plot)

  axis_num <- which(gg$layout[,"name"] == "axis-b")

  xbreaks <- gg[["grobs"]][[axis_num]][["children"]][[2]][["grobs"]][[2]][["children"]][[1]]$x
  if(length(xbreaks) != length(sublabs)) stop("Sub-labels must be the same length as the x-axis breaks")

  to_breaks <- c(as.numeric(xbreaks),1)[which(!duplicated(sublabs, fromLast = TRUE))+1]
  sublabs_x <- diff(c(0,to_breaks))
  sublabs_labels <- sublabs[!duplicated(sublabs, fromLast = TRUE)]

  tg <- tableGrob(matrix(sublabs_labels, nrow = 1))
  tg$widths = unit(sublabs_x, attr(xbreaks,"unit"))

  pos <- gg$layout[axis_num,c("t","l")]

  gg2 <- gtable_add_rows(gg, heights = sum(tg$heights)+unit(4,"mm"), pos = pos$t)
  gg3 <- gtable_add_grob(gg2, tg, t = pos$t+1, l = pos$l)

  return(gg3)
}


#Plot and sublabels
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date, y = value)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 month", date_minor_breaks = "1 month", labels = date_format("%b")) +
  xlab(NULL)
sublabs <- c(rep("1719",2),rep("1720",6))

#Draw
grid.draw(add_sublabs(p, sublabs))
```

[image]

Comment: That's very nice Mike. I can see that this would be a great way to label things like, say, "President X", "President Y" with corresponding matching fill colors. Thumbs up!

Comment: @PatrickT thanks! I edited it to what I think is a slightly better way. I wrote a quick function that takes a vector of sublabels and a plot. I think it's more intuitive/succinct than my original way.

Answer (score 2):

One way to avoid the complexities would be to change the required output so that January is replaced by the year.

The `lab` function returns the labels given the breaks. Unexpectedly, ggplot will pass NAs to it so in the first line of the function body we replace those with some date -- it does not matter which date since such values are not subsequently used by ggplot.  Finally we format the date as a year or abbreviated month depending on whether the month is January (which corresponds to the POSIXlt component `mon` equalling 0) or not.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

lab <- function(b) {
  b[is.na(b)] <- Sys.Date()
  format(b, ifelse(as.POSIXlt(b)$mon == 0, "%Y", "%b"))
}

ggplot(df, aes(Date, value)) + 
   geom_line() +
   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "month", labels = lab)
```

[image: screenshot]

**Note:** I have added [Issue 2182](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2182) to the ggplot2 github issues list regarding the NAs that are passed to the label function.  If subsequent versions of ggplot2 no longer pass the NAs then the first line of the body of `lab` could be omitted .

**Update:** fixed.