# weekdays under hours with ggplot

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I have struggled with this exercise for a while. And I choose to post another question with another type of data being reproduced and modified due to confidentiality reasons.

I am attempting to plot this data based on this example:

[image]

The reproducible example:

```
 test <- structure(list(Rounded_date = structure(c(1420383600, 1420387200, 
                                              1420390800, 1420401600, 1420405200, 1420408800, 1420412400, 1420416000, 
                                              1420419600, 1420423200, 1420426800, 1420430400, 1420434000, 1420437600, 
                                              1420441200, 1420444800, 1420448400, 1420452000, 1420455600, 1420459200, 
                                              1420462800, 1420466400, 1420470000, 1420473600, 1420477200, 1420480800, 
                                              1420484400, 1420488000, 1420491600, 1420495200, 1420498800, 1420502400, 
                                              1420506000, 1420509600, 1420513200, 1420516800, 1420520400, 1420524000, 
                                              1420527600, 1420531200, 1420534800, 1420538400, 1420542000, 1420545600, 
                                              1420549200, 1420552800, 1420556400, 1420560000, 1420563600, 1420567200, 
                                              1420570800, 1420574400, 1420578000, 1420581600, 1420585200, 1420588800, 
                                              1420592400, 1420596000, 1420599600, 1420603200, 1420606800, 1420610400, 
                                              1420614000, 1420617600, 1420621200, 1420624800, 1420628400, 1420632000, 
                                              1420635600, 1420639200, 1420642800, 1420646400, 1420650000, 1420653600, 
                                              1420657200, 1420660800, 1420664400, 1420668000, 1420671600, 1420675200, 
                                              1420678800, 1420682400, 1420686000, 1420689600, 1420693200, 1420696800, 
                                              1420700400, 1420704000, 1420707600, 1420711200, 1420714800, 1420718400, 
                                              1420722000, 1420725600, 1420729200, 1420732800, 1420736400, 1420740000, 
                                              1420743600, 1420747200, 1420750800, 1420754400, 1420758000, 1420761600, 
                                              1420765200, 1420768800, 1420772400, 1420776000, 1420779600, 1420783200, 
                                              1420786800, 1420790400, 1420794000, 1420797600, 1420801200, 1420804800, 
                                              1420808400, 1420812000, 1420815600, 1420819200, 1420822800, 1420826400, 
                                              1420830000, 1420833600, 1420837200, 1420840800, 1420844400, 1420848000, 
                                              1420851600, 1420855200, 1420858800, 1420862400, 1420866000, 1420869600, 
                                              1420873200, 1420876800, 1420880400, 1420884000, 1420887600, 1420891200, 
                                              1420894800, 1420898400, 1420902000, 1420905600, 1420909200, 1420912800, 
                                              1420916400, 1420920000, 1420923600, 1420927200, 1420930800, 1420934400, 
                                              1420938000, 1420941600, 1420945200, 1420948800, 1420952400, 1420956000, 
                                              1420959600, 1420963200, 1420966800, 1420970400, 1420974000, 1420977600, 
                                              1420981200, 1420984800, 1420988400, 1420992000, 1420995600, 1420999200, 
                                              1421002800, 1421006400, 1421010000, 1421013600, 1421017200, 1421020800, 
                                              1421024400, 1421028000, 1421031600, 1421035200, 1421038800, 1421042400, 
                                              1421046000, 1421049600, 1421053200, 1421056800, 1421060400, 1421064000, 
                                              1421067600, 1421071200, 1421074800, 1421078400, 1421082000, 1421085600, 
                                              1421089200, 1421092800, 1421096400, 1421100000, 1421103600, 1421107200, 
                                              1421110800, 1421114400, 1421118000, 1421121600, 1421125200, 1421128800, 
                                              1421132400, 1421139600, 1421143200, 1421146800, 1421150400, 1421154000, 
                                              1421157600, 1421161200, 1421164800, 1421168400, 1421172000, 1421175600, 
                                              1421179200, 1421182800, 1421186400, 1421190000, 1421193600, 1421197200, 
                                              1421200800, 1421204400, 1421208000, 1421211600, 1421215200, 1421218800, 
                                              1421222400, 1421226000, 1421229600, 1421233200, 1421236800, 1421240400, 
                                              1421244000, 1421247600, 1421251200, 1421254800, 1421258400, 1421262000, 
                                              1421265600, 1421269200, 1421272800, 1421276400, 1421280000, 1421283600, 
                                              1421287200, 1421290800, 1421294400, 1421298000, 1421301600, 1421305200, 
                                              1421308800, 1421312400, 1421316000, 1421319600, 1421323200, 1421326800, 
                                              1421330400, 1421334000, 1421337600, 1421341200, 1421344800, 1421348400, 
                                              1421352000, 1421355600, 1421359200, 1421362800, 1421366400, 1421370000, 
                                              1421373600, 1421377200, 1421380800, 1421384400, 1421388000, 1421391600, 
                                              1421395200, 1421398800, 1421402400, 1421406000, 1421409600, 1421413200, 
                                              1421416800, 1421420400, 1421424000, 1421427600, 1421431200, 1421434800, 
                                              1421438400, 1421442000, 1421445600, 1421449200, 1421452800, 1421456400, 
                                              1421460000, 1421463600, 1421467200, 1421470800, 1421478000, 1421481600, 
                                              1421485200, 1421488800, 1421492400, 1421496000, 1421499600, 1421503200, 
                                              1421506800, 1421510400, 1421514000, 1421517600, 1421521200, 1421524800, 
                                              1421528400, 1421532000, 1421535600, 1421539200, 1421542800, 1421546400, 
                                              1421550000, 1421553600, 1421557200, 1421560800, 1421564400, 1421568000, 
                                              1421571600, 1421575200, 1421578800, 1421582400, 1421586000, 1421589600, 
                                              1421593200, 1421596800, 1421600400, 1421604000, 1421607600, 1421611200, 
                                              1421614800, 1421618400, 1421622000, 1421625600, 1421629200, 1421632800, 
                                              1421636400, 1421640000, 1421643600, 1421647200, 1421650800, 1421654400, 
                                              1421658000, 1421661600, 1421665200, 1421668800, 1421672400, 1421676000, 
                                              1421679600, 1421683200, 1421686800, 1421690400, 1421694000, 1421697600, 
                                              1421701200, 1421704800, 1421708400, 1421712000, 1421715600, 1421719200, 
                                              1421722800, 1421726400, 1421730000, 1421733600, 1421737200, 1421740800, 
                                              1421744400, 1421748000, 1421751600, 1421755200, 1421758800, 1421762400, 
                                              1421766000, 1421769600, 1421773200, 1421776800, 1421780400, 1421784000, 
                                              1421787600, 1421791200, 1421794800, 1421798400, 1421802000, 1421805600, 
                                              1421809200, 1421812800, 1421816400, 1421820000, 1421823600, 1421827200, 
                                              1421830800, 1421834400, 1421838000, 1421841600, 1421845200, 1421848800, 
                                              1421852400, 1421856000, 1421859600, 1421863200, 1421866800, 1421870400, 
                                              1421874000, 1421877600, 1421881200, 1421884800, 1421888400, 1421892000, 
                                              1421895600, 1421899200, 1421902800, 1421906400, 1421910000, 1421913600, 
                                              1421917200, 1421920800, 1421924400, 1421928000, 1421931600, 1421935200, 
                                              1421938800, 1421942400, 1421946000, 1421949600, 1421953200, 1421956800, 
                                              1421960400, 1421964000, 1421967600, 1421971200, 1421974800, 1421978400, 
                                              1421982000, 1421985600, 1421989200, 1421992800, 1421996400, 1.422e+09, 
                                              1422003600, 1422007200, 1422010800, 1422014400, 1422018000, 1422021600, 
                                              1422025200, 1422028800, 1422032400, 1422036000, 1422039600, 1422043200, 
                                              1422046800, 1422050400, 1422054000, 1422057600, 1422061200, 1422064800, 
                                              1422068400, 1422072000, 1422075600, 1422079200, 1422082800, 1422086400, 
                                              1422090000, 1422093600, 1422097200, 1422100800, 1422104400, 1422108000, 
                                              1422111600, 1422115200, 1422118800, 1422122400, 1422126000, 1422129600, 
                                              1422133200, 1422136800, 1422140400, 1422144000, 1422147600, 1422151200, 
                                              1422154800, 1422158400, 1422162000, 1422165600, 1422169200, 1422172800, 
                                              1422176400, 1422180000, 1422183600, 1422187200, 1422190800, 1422194400, 
                                              1422198000, 1422201600, 1422205200, 1422208800, 1422212400, 1422216000, 
                                              1422219600, 1422223200, 1422226800, 1422230400, 1422234000, 1422237600, 
                                              1422241200, 1422244800, 1422248400, 1422252000, 1422255600, 1422259200, 
                                              1422262800, 1422266400, 1422270000, 1422273600, 1422277200, 1422280800, 
                                              1422284400, 1422288000, 1422291600, 1422295200, 1422298800, 1422302400, 
                                              1422306000, 1422309600, 1422313200, 1422316800, 1422320400, 1422324000, 
                                              1422327600, 1422331200, 1422334800, 1422338400, 1422342000, 1422345600, 
                                              1422349200, 1422352800, 1422356400, 1422360000, 1422363600, 1422367200, 
                                              1422370800, 1422374400, 1422378000, 1422381600, 1422385200, 1422388800, 
                                              1422392400, 1422396000, 1422399600, 1422403200, 1422406800, 1422410400, 
                                              1422414000, 1422417600, 1422421200, 1422424800, 1422428400, 1422432000, 
                                              1422435600, 1422439200, 1422442800, 1422446400, 1422450000, 1422453600, 
                                              1422457200, 1422460800, 1422464400, 1422468000, 1422471600, 1422475200, 
                                              1422478800, 1422482400, 1422486000, 1422489600, 1422493200, 1422496800, 
                                              1422500400, 1422504000, 1422507600, 1422511200, 1422514800, 1422518400, 
                                              1422522000, 1422525600, 1422529200, 1422532800, 1422536400, 1422540000, 
                                              1422543600, 1422547200, 1422550800, 1422554400), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                         "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), n = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                                          8L, 8L, 10L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 15L, 10L, 19L, 13L, 19L, 
                                                                                                                                          18L, 19L, 21L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 
                                                                                                                                          4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 15L, 13L, 18L, 16L, 20L, 18L, 
                                                                                                                                          14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                          6L, 5L, 16L, 9L, 18L, 17L, 11L, 14L, 12L, 17L, 13L, 12L, 10L, 
                                                                                                                                          23L, 8L, 11L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 15L, 
                                                                                                                                          23L, 12L, 12L, 21L, 23L, 15L, 11L, 18L, 18L, 7L, 11L, 16L, 11L, 
                                                                                                                                          9L, 14L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 16L, 20L, 12L, 19L, 
                                                                                                                                          20L, 14L, 16L, 22L, 18L, 13L, 15L, 10L, 18L, 16L, 8L, 9L, 14L, 
                                                                                                                                          7L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 18L, 14L, 11L, 8L, 17L, 11L, 
                                                                                                                                          13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 
                                                                                                                                          7L, 4L, 12L, 18L, 14L, 10L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 12L, 14L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                          15L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                          15L, 23L, 12L, 22L, 14L, 16L, 19L, 18L, 16L, 14L, 9L, 18L, 11L, 
                                                                                                                                          12L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 7L, 6L, 14L, 
                                                                                                                                          15L, 6L, 11L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                          4L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 16L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 17L, 14L, 19L, 13L, 
                                                                                                                                          11L, 14L, 13L, 17L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 11L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                          4L, 9L, 10L, 17L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 15L, 19L, 11L, 
                                                                                                                                          10L, 8L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 15L, 
                                                                                                                                          14L, 11L, 9L, 16L, 13L, 11L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                                          3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 12L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 8L, 11L, 
                                                                                                                                          16L, 7L, 18L, 8L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 
                                                                                                                                          6L, 2L, 9L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 14L, 13L, 17L, 12L, 10L, 
                                                                                                                                          16L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 12L, 20L, 18L, 
                                                                                                                                          24L, 12L, 13L, 20L, 18L, 19L, 18L, 27L, 13L, 16L, 12L, 9L, 8L, 
                                                                                                                                          10L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 12L, 8L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                          13L, 15L, 9L, 17L, 17L, 11L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                          4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 16L, 13L, 18L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 7L, 
                                                                                                                                          14L, 17L, 19L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 
                                                                                                                                          6L, 5L, 17L, 16L, 11L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 23L, 17L, 22L, 12L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                          14L, 15L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 11L, 10L, 
                                                                                                                                          16L, 16L, 21L, 13L, 20L, 18L, 16L, 24L, 12L, 21L, 6L, 12L, 15L, 
                                                                                                                                          9L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 11L, 15L, 14L, 
                                                                                                                                          15L, 12L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 17L, 6L, 6L, 
                                                                                                                                          8L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 17L, 14L, 
                                                                                                                                          12L, 18L, 16L, 9L, 17L, 15L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                          6L, 9L, 15L, 23L, 17L, 20L, 17L, 25L, 23L, 18L, 8L, 19L, 15L, 
                                                                                                                                          18L, 11L, 16L, 13L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 11L, 
                                                                                                                                          11L, 6L, 20L, 21L, 6L, 19L, 11L, 18L, 15L, 17L, 14L, 12L, 10L, 
                                                                                                                                          8L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 14L, 12L, 14L, 
                                                                                                                                          13L, 15L, 14L, 22L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
                                                                                                                                          1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 13L, 11L, 10L, 15L, 21L, 12L, 14L, 
                                                                                                                                          18L, 16L)), row.names = c(NA, -600L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                          "data.frame"))
```

As observed within the example provided, I need the averages based on hour and weekday, min and max, and the confidence intervals.

I have attempted to achieve the mean, max and confidence intervals with this code BUT ON DIFFERENT TYPE OF DATA. This is because, again, as I have mentioned, my data is confidential and cannot disclose it. But as you can see, I have counted the occupancy, that is n (counts) in the reproduced data. This will enable to get the min, max, and confidence intervals.

```
#extracting year, month, day and hour from Time column and count = occupancy

    dt_sep <- dt_hrs %>%
      mutate(
        Time = ymd_hms(Time),
        Rounded_date = round_date(Time, "hour"), 
        month = month(Rounded_date),
        day = wday(Rounded_date, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE),
        hour = hms::as.hms(Rounded_date)
      ) %>%
      dplyr::count(Rounded_date)


    dput(head(dt_sep, 100)) # THIS ENABLED THE REPRODUCIBLE DATA provided above(with changes due to confidentiality)


    # getting the averages, min, max, interquartile ranges (Q1 and  Q3)
    tbl_avg_occ <- dt_sep %>%
      group_by(hour, day) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(Average_occ = mean(n), 
                       Q1 = quantile(n, 0.025), 
                       Q3 = quantile(n, 0.975), 
                       Min_n = min(n), 
                       Max_n = max(n)) %>%
      ungroup()
```

And then ordered the weekdays to start with Monday, as Europe counts the beginning of the week with Monday, rather with Sunday.

```
library(plyr)
Weekdays <- c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun") 
tbl_avg_occ_2 <-arrange(transform(tbl_avg_occ, day = factor(day, levels = Weekdays)), day)
```

And then plotted with this code, which of course does not get the output as in the plot provided since I have used the facet_wrap, yet want to avoid this function.

```
plt <-  tbl_avg_occ_2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hour, y = Average_occ, group = day, colour = day)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.5, colour = "blue") +
  facet_wrap( ~ day, nrow = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 23), ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 80)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Q1, ymax = Q3), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Min_n, ymax = Max_n), alpha = 0.1) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Can someone help me? This task to be achieved with tidyverse.

Comment: Can you upload the output and add it to your question?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52599824/

Comment: thank you, will try it as soon as I can.

Comment: @Tung - I can't do the way you have done it since firstly, I have min, max, interquartile range. tried to bring the data into your format, yet cannot plot it. However, my question is - can I plot the hours, from 0 to 23:00 (being in one column) and week day into another one column. Can I plot 2 columns on x axis? These being extracted from dates, of course.