# how to hide/remove part of x axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a bubble plot with geom_point() in RStudio, but there are lots of white space between x = -0.25 to x = 0.25 . I wonder if there is a way to hide this part so that my plot looks more compact.
[image]

Comment: You can separate them into two group and use `facet_` + remove spacing. Something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/q/52554822/786542

Comment: thanks, this is what I want.