# add a level of nesting/grouping to x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to add a second layer of grouping to the x-axis as show in the panel for Outcome A below. There should be two points for each estimate type (ITT vs TOT) that correspond to the label 3 or 12.

[image]

Here's my approach to get what you see, minus the edits to the Outcome A panel:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=factor(estimate), y=gd, group=interaction(estimate, time), shape=estimate)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=gd.lwr, ymax=gd.upr), width=0.1,
                position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  ylim(-1, 1) +
  facet_wrap(~outcome, scales='free', strip.position = "top") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

Here's the toy data:

```
df <- structure(list(outcome = c("Outcome C", "Outcome C", "Outcome C", 
"Outcome C", "Outcome B", "Outcome B", "Outcome B", "Outcome B", 
"Outcome A", "Outcome A", "Outcome A", "Outcome A"), estimate = c("ITT", 
"ITT", "TOT", "TOT", "ITT", "ITT", "TOT", "TOT", "ITT", "ITT", 
"TOT", "TOT"), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("3", "12"), class = "factor"), 
    gd = c(0.12, -0.05, 0.19, -0.08, -0.22, -0.05, -0.34, -0.07, 
    0.02, -0.02, 0.03, -0.03), gd.lwr = c(-0.07, -0.28, -0.11, 
    -0.45, -0.43, -0.27, -0.69, -0.42, -0.21, -0.22, -0.33, -0.36
    ), gd.upr = c(0.31, 0.18, 0.5, 0.29, 0, 0.17, 0.01, 0.27, 
    0.24, 0.19, 0.38, 0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: possible duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616530/axis-labels-on-two-lines-with-nested-x-variables-year-below-months

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multirow axis labels with nested grouping variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165863/multirow-axis-labels-with-nested-grouping-variables)

Comment: Thanks, @iod. I came across that answer, but I posted thinking there might be a better way given all the development on ggplot since 2010.

Comment: Thanks, @Mike. In the example you pointed to there is only 1 faceting term, but I think I'd need to use at least 2 since I already facet on `outcome`. The results don't look quite right.

Comment: No problem, what I would do is split your graphs by outcome and then use `grid.arrange` to put them back together

Comment: Just btw, you could consider removing all the visual fluff (e.g., all `theme` calls) and superfluous data (e.g., most of the dataframe was not needed) from your question next time to speed up understanding :-)

Comment: Good point, @Roman. I simplified the dataframe.

Comment: @EricGreen I updated my answer to remove duplicate legends, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Roman, Mike, and camille for thinking through this problem and posting great ideas. I think people will find value in each approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a perfect solution, but it's perhaps more scaleable. It's based on the ["shared legends"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/shared_legends.html) vignette from `cowplot`.

I'm splitting the data by outcomes, then using `purrr::imap` to make a list of three identical plots, rather than creating them individually or otherwise hardcoding anything. Then I'm using 2 `cowplot` functions, one to extract the legend as a `ggplot`/`gtable` object, and one to build a grid of plots and other plot-like objects.

Each plot is done for just one outcome, with `time`—either 3 or 12—on the x-axis, and facetted by `estimate`. Similar to how you did, the facets are disguised to look more like subtitles.

There are some design concerns that you'll probably want to tweak further. For example, I adjusted the scale expansion to make padding between groups to get the look you posted. I traded the panel border for axis lines to keep from having a border in the middle of each plot, since it will draw in between the facets—there might be a better way to do this.

```r
library(tidyverse)

plot_list <- df %>%
  split(.$outcome) %>%
  imap(function(sub_df, outcome_name) {
    ggplot(sub_df, aes(x = as_factor(time), y = gd, shape = estimate)) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = gd.lwr, ymax = gd.upr), width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
      geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
      scale_x_discrete(expand = expand_scale(add = 2)) +
      ylim(-1, 1) +
      facet_wrap(~ estimate, strip.position = "bottom") +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
            panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
            strip.background = element_blank(),
            strip.placement = "outside", 
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      labs(title = outcome_name)
  })
```

Each plot in the list is then:

```r
plot_list[[1]]
```

[image]

Extract the legend, then map over the list of plots to remove their legends.

```r
legend <- cowplot::get_legend(plot_list[[1]])

no_legends <- plot_list %>%
  map(~{. + theme(legend.position = "none")})
```

One thing that was more manual than I would have preferred was messing with the labels. I opted for setting blank labels instead of `NULL` so there would still be empty text as placeholders, thus keeping the plots the same sizes. Because of needing to remove some labels, you do miss out on one nice feature of `plot_grid`, which is passing an entire list of plots in.

```r
gridded <- cowplot::plot_grid(
  no_legends[[1]] + labs(x = ""),
  no_legends[[2]] + labs(y = ""),
  no_legends[[3]] + labs(x = "", y = ""),
  nrow = 1
)
```

Then make an additional grid where you add the legend to the right side and scale the widths accordingly:

```r
cowplot::plot_grid(gridded, legend, nrow = 1, rel_widths = c(1, 0.2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: On that note, maybe `patchwork` would be more straight-forward?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about `patchwork` since I've been switching some things from `cowplot` to `patchwork`, but wanted to make use of `cowplot::get_legend`. That function is super handy for things like this, and AFAIK `patchwork` doesn't have something similar

Answer (score 3):

[image: 1]

Changed `x` aesthetic to `interaction(time, factor(estimate))` and added a fitting discrete labels.

```
df %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = interaction(time, factor(estimate)),                   # relevant
                y = gd, group = interaction(estimate, time), 
                shape = estimate)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = gd.lwr, ymax = gd.upr), width = 0.1,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  ylim(-1, 1) +
  facet_wrap(~outcome, scales = 'free', strip.position = "top") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("3\nITT", "12\nITT", "3\nTOT", "12\nTOT"))   # relevant
```

Comment: Thanks. @Roman. Helpful insight about the modification to `x`. Interesting approach with the discrete labels. Is it the case that if I wanted to have only one "ITT" and one "TOT" label (centered) for each pair of 3/12 points, I would need to use an approach like the one @Mike describes?

Comment: I will probably use your solution in practice because it gets me very close with simple code. Marked a different answer "correct" because it solved the super-label challenge.

Comment: That's absolutely okay and deserved, I'm happy that it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Posting a solution using `grid.arrange`. I updated the answer to only include one legend.

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)

   p1 <- ggplot(filter(df, outcome == "Outcome A"), 
             aes(x = time,                   # relevant
                    y = gd, group = interaction(estimate, time), 
                    shape = estimate)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = gd.lwr, ymax = gd.upr), width = 0.1,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  ylim(-1, 1) +
  scale_x_discrete("")+
  facet_wrap(~estimate, scales = 'free_x', strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "bottom",
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color="white")) +
  ggtitle("Outcome A")



p2 <- ggplot(filter(df, outcome == "Outcome B"), 
             aes(x = time,                   # relevant
                 y = gd, group = interaction(estimate, time), 
                 shape = estimate)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = gd.lwr, ymax = gd.upr), width = 0.1,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  ylim(-1, 1) +
  scale_x_discrete("")+
  facet_wrap(~estimate, scales = 'free_x', strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "bottom",
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color="white")) +
  ggtitle("Outcome B")

p3 <-  ggplot(filter(df, outcome == "Outcome C"), 
              aes(x = time,                   # relevant
                  y = gd, group = interaction(estimate, time), 
                  shape = estimate)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = gd.lwr, ymax = gd.upr), width = 0.1,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  ylim(-1, 1) +
  scale_x_discrete("")+
  facet_wrap(~estimate, scales = 'free_x', strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "bottom",
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color="white")) +
  ggtitle("Outcome C")


#layout matrix for the 3 plots and one legend

lay <- rbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4),
             c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4))


g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)}
#return one legend for plot 
aleg <- g_legend(p1)
gp1 <- p1+ theme(legend.position = "none")
gp2 <- p2+ theme(legend.position = "none")
gp3 <- p3+ theme(legend.position = "none")



gridExtra::grid.arrange(gp1,gp2,gp3,aleg, layout_matrix = lay)
```

[image]