# how to make a Line plot with mean+ error bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, errorbar

I am trying to make a line chart but failed. I am not generating the code for this. we have the mean and std error. Means of the month need to be grouped with a different color. I generated the graph in excel but it would be better for me to generate in R.
My data are 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eatap.png)
[image]

I want to look such kind of image. It was made in excel. Please, help me to fix the problem

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit the question to include your code and enough data to reproduce the graph (use `dput(my_data)`) to make the data easy to import

Comment: The sooner you learn about ggplot2, the better. Check out https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_linerange.html

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the following code.

Prepare your data as a dataframe, like the one shown below.
You can use `read.csv` to read data from a CSV file.

```
> data
       Month            season POC   sd_min   sd_max
1       June       Pre Monsoon 125 114.0564 135.9436
2       July Southwest Monsoon 145 137.9181 152.0819
3     August Northeast Monsoon 155 151.0996 158.9004
4  September Northeast Monsoon 155 145.0982 164.9018
5    October Northeast Monsoon 156 152.6262 159.3738
6   November  SouthwestMonsoon 152 134.6723 169.3277
7   December  SouthwestMonsoon 100  98.3175 101.6825
8    January       Pre Monsoon 150 143.3171 156.6829
9   February       Pre Monsoon 110 107.9925 112.0075
10     March       Pre Monsoon 153 148.8530 157.1470
11     April       Pre Monsoon 148 144.7181 151.2819
12       May  SouthwestMonsoon 146 141.7141 150.2859
```

NOTE: `data$Month` should be a factor with the levels ordered according to the order desired in the x-axis of the plot.

```
data$Month <- factor(data$Month, levels = data$Month)
```

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = Month, y = POC, group = 1)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
 + geom_errorbar(ymax = data$sd_max, ymin = data$sd_min, width = 0.25)
 + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.95 * min(data$sd_min), 1.05 * max(data$sd_max)),
   expand = FALSE, clip = "off") + theme_bw()
```

[image: Fig-1]

To have a second layer of x-axis labeling you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20574024/5607735) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44616739/5607735)

Comment: How to calculate sd_max and sd_min. Truly speaking, I get only a single sd from a mean in excel. However, thanks for the comment

Comment: Like this, `sd_min =  mean - sd/2` and `sd_max = mean - sd/2`.

Comment: The problem arises in the adding of the error bar such as Error: Cannot use `+.gg()` with a single argument. Did you accidentally put + on a new line? After generating the line the above problem  arise. indicating "+geom_errorbar " this line show wrong.

Comment: Sorry, they are different: `sd_min = mean - sd/2` and `sd_max = mean + sd/2`. I split the line with ggplot for readability. They should be in the same line. Sorry about that.

Comment: Boss, the second layer of the X-axis in a line plot shows wrong.  One is done but maintaining the same quartile. But in my case, Southwest monsoon=4 Months, Northeast monsoon=3 months, pre monsoon=3 months and post monssoon= 2 months, Then what can I do? Please, provide a dummy example as above the first figure you done.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I am not familiar with how to make a second layer of x-axis. You can do it manually. You could export the image as an SVG file and use Inscape to edit it.